# should entity field be mutable or immutable

Tags: scala, immutability

In a scala project, should entity field be mutable or immutable ?

Mutable field:

It is very easy to change field in a nested entity, also when logic is pushed into entity, it is very easy to be implemented.

Immutable field:

It guarantees consensus for one system is running, but it still may have inconsistency data if more than one systems are running, Also, if entity fields are immutable, it has lots of boilerplates to update nested fields. That means that some concept like lens should be introduced.

What should I choose to start up a scala project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always favor immutability.  Definitely in Scala, and probably in every other language too.

It's hard to give a more specific answer without a more specific question.  But immutability is almost always a safe answer.